# Fill empty values in running sum

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've to calculate a ratio between several categories everytime one some category gets a value change.

If I have the following table:

| Block | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 30 |
| 1 | B | 20 |
| 1 | C | 50 |
| 2 | A | 40 |
| 4 | B | 10 |

I'd need a way to get the running sum filling empty values (Category A without changes since block 1) with the nearest preceding one:

| Block | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 30 |
| 1 | B | 20 |
| 1 | C | 50 |
| 2 | A | 70 |
| 2 | B | 20 |
| 2 | C | 50 |
| 4 | A | 70 |
| 4 | B | 30 |
| 4 | C | 50 |

I'm using a query like the following one:

```
SELECT category, block_number
  SUM(block_sum) OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY block_number)
  FROM block_table
```

But in the case there's no value from a given category in a block_number, then I won't get that row in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the rows using a `cross join`.  Use a `left join` to bring in the values that exist and then use window functions:

```
select b.block, bc.category,
       sum(bt.value) over (partition by c.category order by b.block) as value
from (select distinct block from block_table) b cross join
     (select distinct category from block_table) c left join
     block_table bt
     on b.block = bt.block and c.category = bt.category;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Before I accept the answer as correct I'd like to ask you if you could give me more details about the answer. I'm not understanding it fully, specially the part with the cross join/left join combination. I don't fully understand why it can fill the missing values with the nearest preceding one.

Comment: @Rod0n . . . That is because the cumulative sum ignores `NULL` values.  The `left join` generates `NULL` values for the missing rows -- and the cumulative sum does what you want.